# I cant generate a random number and print it

Tags: python, random, tkinter

I can't generate the number because I get the error NameError: name 'z' is not defined.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

def randomize():
    z.set ( randint(x.get(),y.get()))

root = tk.Tk()

x = tk.IntVar()
y = tk.IntVar()

text= tk.Label(root, text = "press the button for random number")
enterX = tk.Entry(root)
enterY = tk.Entry(root)
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Press here", command=randomize)
result = tk.Label(root,text="Number is:")
number = tk.Label(root, textvariable=z)

text.pack()
enterX.pack()
enterY.pack()
button.pack()
result.pack()
number.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I need help to resolve the error

Comment: Variable `z` isn't defined in your code

Comment: It can't be defined inside the function? As I've done

Comment: For future reference: please paste in the full traceback too, not just the error you get.

Comment: Ok, thank for help

Comment: The first step you should do to debug this is put in some print statements in `randomize` to verify that the values you're _assuming_ you're getting and computing are what you're _actually_ getting and computing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems here.

One. You are missing `z = tk.Intvar()` in the global namespace.

Two. You need to assign each entry field one of the IntVar()'s.

Keep in mind that you are not validating the entry fields so if someone types anything other than a whole number you will run into an error.

Take a look at this code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

def randomize():
    z.set(randint(x.get(),y.get()))
    print(z.get()) # added print statement to verify results.

root = tk.Tk()

x = tk.IntVar()
y = tk.IntVar()
z = tk.IntVar() # added IntVar()

text= tk.Label(root, text = "press the button for random number")
enterX = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=x) # added textvariable
enterY = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=y) # added textvariable
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Press here", command=randomize)
result = tk.Label(root,text="Number is:")
number = tk.Label(root, textvariable=z)

text.pack()
enterX.pack()
enterY.pack()
button.pack()
result.pack()
number.pack()

root.mainloop()
```